# Slow copying of files from Bricked NAS to computer via USB 3.0 to SATA

Tags: hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, sata, nas

Unfortunately I bricked my "Western Digital MyBookLive 3TB" network hard drive. (Only had an ethernet port to access files via network)

After realising it was not going to work again, I decided to take it apart and order a USB 3.0 to SATA adapter to get my important files back.

Using a MacBook Air with 3.0 USB ports and using fuse-ext2 I am able to read access my files. I am trying to copy the files I need but there is a serious bottleneck somewhere.

Currently I am trying to copy 6GB of photos to my laptop, it has been copying for 5 hours and it has only copied 450MB so far with an estimated 2 days remaining. Here's an [image](http://s22.postimg.org/qep8u9hm9/Screen_Shot_2013_10_01_at_13_34_40.png)

Could anyone explain anyway of making copying a bit faster, and what might be causing the snail pace transfers. I was able to copy my files over the network 100x faster (before it broke :P)!

Also I was reading somewhere that WD made the block size 64k instead of 4k... I must admit I have no idea what this means and how it might effect copying data.

Comment: Information on the exact model of the hdd and the adapter you are using.  This sound more of a hardware issue then a bottleneck problem to be honest.

Comment: Have you considered that the drive itself is failing?  Have you run WD's diagnostics against it?

Comment: This might be a fuse-ex2 problem.  I've read similar reports. Have you tried [OSXFUSE](http://osxfuse.github.io/)?

Comment: Do you happen to have an Anti Virus running on your Mac? (We have had a case in our workplace where Anti Virus would make their time machine backup crawls to a halt. As soon as the Anti Virus temporarily stopped / removed / disable on-access scanning - it speeds up to normal)